# Send aggregate code coverage in a java gradle multi module project to Sonarqube

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, junit, sonarqube

We are building a multi module spring boot project. Each project has a set of tests and some modules are dependent on each other.(The dependencies are not circular obviously!).

Now we have a problem that the code coverage report is not generated and thus we cannot send it to sonar.

The structure of the project is as follows:

```
root
|
|------ build.gradle
|------ setting.gradle
|------ gradle.properties
|
|_______Project1
|   |------ build
|   |------ src
|   |------ build.gradle
|
|_______Project2
|   |------ build
|   |------ src
|   |------ build.gradle
|
|_______Project3
|   |------ build
|   |------ src
|   |------ build.gradle
```

the root project does not contain any src folder. It is a just a container for subprojects.

in each subproject, the `build.gradle` file is just something like this:

```
dependencies {
    //some dependencies...

}
```

they only contains dependencies.

the `build.gradle` in root project, however, is like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.6.6'
        hibernateVersion = '5.6.1.Final'
        springCloudStarterVersion = '3.1.0'
        mapStructVersion = '1.5.2.Final'
        lombokVersion = '1.18.22'
        sentryVersion = '5.0.1'
        sonarVersion = '4.4.1.3373'
        openApiVersion = '1.6.2'
    }
    repositories {
        // a local repo
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:${sonarVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.sonarqube' version "${sonarVersion}"
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'jacoco-report-aggregation'
}


allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    group 'co.mahsan.iam.commons'

    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco-report-aggregation'


    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.required = true
            csv.required = true
            html.required = true
        }
    }
    check.dependsOn jacocoTestReport

    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        reports {
            junitXml.required = true
            html.required = true
        }
    }
    jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
    }

    java {
        withSourcesJar()
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    // internal repos
    }


    dependencies {
        // required dependencies 
    }


    def importJUnitResultsToXrayDC = tasks.register('importJUnitResultsToXrayDC', Exec) {
        description 'Imports Junit test results to Xray Test Management for Jira DC.'
        onlyIf {
            System.getenv().containsKey('JIRA_HOST')
        }

        def env = System.getenv()
        // the following variables can be defined locally or in gradle.properties
        //  - jiraBaseUrl, jiraUsername, jiraPassword
        //  - reportFormat, projectKey version, revision, testPlanKey, testExecKey, testEnvironment

        def reportFile = "build/test-results/xray/iam-panel-test-result.xml"

        def url = "${env.JIRA_HOST}/rest/raven/2.0/import/execution/${reportFormat}?"
        

    // send the reportFile to jira
    }


//    test.configure {
//        finalizedBy importJUnitResultsToXrayDC
//    }

 
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
    sonarqube {
        properties {

            property 'sonar.exclusions', some exclusions
            property 'sonar.coverage.exclusions', some exclusions
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is, as far as I find out, that java will build each module in its directory build folder. the code coverage reports are also generated seperately in those build folders. But I need to create an aggregated coverage report from all those reports and place it in the `build` folder of the root project.(which does not  create automatically due to the structure of our project.)

What Should I do for this issue, How can I generate an aggregated coverage report with Jacoco and Junit and gradle? the gradle version is 8.5.

P.S: It's good to mention that some modules are using spring boot 2.6.6, while others are using spring boot 3x.